# Can the Lenovo X220 Tablet serve as a WiFi HotSpot?

Tags: wireless-networking, thinkpad, hotspot

I want to let other devices connect via WiFi to my new ThinkPad X220 (tablet). I'm running Kubuntu 12.04. How do I determine if my X220 will function as a WiFi HotSpot?

Here is the info hwinfo returned:

```
29: PCI 300.0: 0282 WLAN controller
  [Created at pci.318]
  Unique ID: y9xn.yysjQBRxxxx
  Parent ID: qTxu.yyApgoxxxxx
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:03:00.0
  SysFS BusID: 0000:03:00.0
  Hardware Class: network
  Model: "Intel WLAN controller"
  Vendor: pci 0x8086 "Intel Corporation"
  Device: pci 0x0085 
  SubVendor: pci 0x8086 "Intel Corporation"
  SubDevice: pci 0x1311 
  Revision: 0x34
  Driver: "iwlwifi"
  Driver Modules: "iwlwifi"
  Device File: wlan0
  Features: WLAN
  Memory Range: 0xf2400000-0xf2401fff (rw,non-prefetchable)
  IRQ: 44 (5518978 events)
  HW Address: xxxxxxxxxxxxx
  Link detected: yes
  WLAN channels: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 36 40 44 48 52 56 60 64 100 104 108 112 116 120 124 128 132 136 140
  WLAN frequencies: 2.412 2.417 2.422 2.427 2.432 2.437 2.442 2.447 2.452 2.457 2.462 2.467 2.472 5.18 5.2 5.22 5.24 5.26 5.28 5.3 5.32 5.5 5.52 5.54 5.56 5.58 5.6 5.62 5.64 5.66 5.68 5.7
  WLAN encryption modes: WEP40 WEP104 TKIP CCMP
  WLAN authentication modes: open sharedkey wpa-psk wpa-eap
  Module Alias: "pci:v00008086d00000085sv00008086sd00001311bc02sc80i00"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: iwlwifi is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe iwlwifi"
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
  Attached to: #22 (PCI bridge)
```

UPDATE: [this forum post](http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/X-Series-Tablet-ThinkPad-Laptops/Sharing-WiFi-internet-access-from-X220-Tablet/td-p/726337) indicates the X220 can act as a WiFi HotSpot. If that is correct, then I have to figure out why Kubuntu won't facilitate this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iwlwifi is a proprietary driver.
choosing opensource driver like madwifi would allow ubuntu to configure the card as access point.

Answer (score 1):

Create an ad-hoc connection. other devices will then connect to that access point.

[This link](http://exain.wordpress.com/2011/03/31/making-a-wifi-hotspot-access-point-using-linux-wifi-lan-cardusb-adapter/) may be helpful.